# result based on maximum date with groupBy in laravel

Tags: laravel, group-by, max

Here i want to fetch results based on the maximum date from the field so in order to get that i wrote query like this

```
$latest_reports = Filelist::
                      select('report_type_id',DB::raw('filename,max(data_date) as latest_date'))
                     ->where('access_id','=',$retailer_supplier_id->id)
                     ->groupBy('report_type_id')
                     ->orderBy('data_date','desc') 
                     ->get();
```

Here is my table please have a look

```
id    access_id   filename      report_type_id    data_date

1       16        filename1            6         2021-02-01

2       16        filename2            6         2021-01-01

3       16        filename3            6         2021-03-01

4       16        filename4            6         2021-04-01
```

Am getting result like this

```
id    access_id   filename      report_type_id    data_date

4       16        filename1            6         2021-04-01
```

I want to get result like this

```
id    access_id   filename      report_type_id    data_date

4       16        filename4            6         2021-04-01
```

Here the first rows `filename` value is getting..how to solve this

Comment: Is the column data_date of date type?

Comment: @HarisShah no it's of string

Comment: did you try to use latest_date in orderBy function?

Comment: yes i tested that but same result

Comment: try to use str_to_date() function on data_date and then order the data

Comment: example STR_TO_DATE(max(data_date),'%d,%m,%Y');

Comment: any idea any body have

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

```
$latest_reports = Filelist::select([
            'report_type_id',
            'access_id'
            DB::raw('MAX(data_date) AS data_date'),
            // here can be listed the other fields
        ])
            ->where('access_id', $retailer_supplier_id->id)
            ->groupBy('report_type_id')
            ->get();
```

**INITIAL:**

I had similar working query, just there I had "created_at" timestamp field. Anyway, I think this will work for you:

```
// assuming, that your table name is "filelist"
$latest_reports = Filelist::select(DB::raw('t.*'))
            ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM filelist ORDER BY data_date DESC) t'))
            ->groupBy('t.report_type_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: is that caused an error or you got something else?

Comment: what exactly? please provide that, or just example of that

Comment: `id    access_id   filename      report_type_id    data_date

4       16        filename1            6                   2021-02-01`

Comment: Sorry for delay, I was AFK. Anyway I've edited the answer, so if you didn't found what you need, then there you can test the new simple query.

Comment: sorry for the delay,the `filename` which i gave inside your select query gets same output

Answer (score 0):

This is a MySQL problem I think. You have specified only one column to group by, but more then one column in the select list so what is presented in those other non-aggregating columns isn't guaranteed to be sensible. Please refer to [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

In SQL I might re-write the query this way:

```
select * from mytable 
where data_date = (select max(data_date) from mytable)
```

or

```
select * from mytable 
order by data_date
limit 1
```

depending on my particular needs (and I don't know which is better for you)